# ¿Como buscar en JQGRID?

Tags: jqgrid

tengo cierto problema, al querer hacer una busqueda mi jqgrid solo busca por una columna y no más, quiero buscar por 3 campos y solo una columna sirve para búsqueda. ¡alguna idea?
Quiero hacer la busqueda de forma normal sobre la tabla,
Ya intente lo que dice en la documentacion con el search : true en cada columna que quiero, pero eso solo me habilita o deshabilita la caja de busqueda.

Answer (score 0):

Aqui te dejo una funcion que me permite buscar por cualquier campo mostrado en tu grilla:

**definiendo la Grilla y el input de busqueda:**

```
<input type="text" id="#search_cells">
<table id="gridEjemplo"></table>
<div id="pagerEjemplo"></div>
```

**en tu archivo js**

```
        //funcion Buscar
        var timer;
        $("#search_cells").on("keyup", function() {
            var self = this;
            if(timer) { clearTimeout(timer); }
            timer = setTimeout(function(){
                //timer = null;
                $("#gridEjemplo").jqGrid('filterInput', self.value);
            },0);
        });
```

con esta funcion te buscara por cualquier campo mostrado en tu grid..
espero te sirva..!!